# No visible text() when using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib==1.5.2
pylab==0.1.3

I am trying to reproduce a graph from the course ["CS224d Deep Learning for NLP"](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html), [Lecture 2](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lectures/CS224d-Lecture2.pdf).

It should look the following way:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

la = np.linalg

words = ['I', 'like', 'enjoy', 'deep', 'learning', 'NLP', 'flying', '.'] 

X = np.array([[0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
              [2,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]])

U, s, Vh = la.svd(X, full_matrices=False)

for i in xrange(len(words)):
    plt.text(U[i,0], U[i,1], words[i])

plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

However, the words don't appear on the graph.

If I remove the instruction

```
plt.autoscale()
```

- I can see some text plotted in the corner, but the axis range is wrong.

If I use this instruction, then I see no text at all, even if I call *text()* once again.

I have seen solutions with using subplots and setting the exact ranges for *x* and *y* axis, but this seems to be unnecessarily complex.

What else can I try?

Comment: Seems like `plt.autoscale()` does not work with text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the words when you set axis limits to show the text as per this answer below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

la = np.linalg

words = ['I', 'like', 'enjoy', 'deep', 'learning', 'NLP', 'flying', '.'] 

X = np.array([[0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
              [2,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]])

U, s, Vh = la.svd(X, full_matrices=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in xrange(len(words)):
    ax.text(U[i,0], U[i,1], words[i])

ax.set_xlim([-0.8, 0.2])
ax.set_ylim([-0.8, 0.8])
plt.show()
```